# How to store Image, retrieved from Firebase, in localStorage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to store User Profile Picture in localStorage via JavaScript from the Firebase after he logged in his account. But I am getting no result.

Actually, we have to get the URL of the image we want to use on the website from the firebase. So I am storing that URL in local storage, but it is not working at all

The code I used is given below-

```
nameOfImageIWantToDownload.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){

    localStorage.setItem("userProfile", url);


});
```

Comment: Is the image not being stored on the local storage? What is the exact problem?

Comment: I think it should be `window.localStorage.setItem("userProfile", url);`

Comment: @Vakore window object is automatically implied. I don't think that is the issue

Comment: Try to `console.log` the url, if need be

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What is `url` when you do `console.log(url);`?

Comment: @AbhishekMehandiratta yes, I tried the console.log and it is showing the "undefined"

Comment: @KAPILSHARMA then you know what the issue is, you are not obtaining the download url properly... check this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: @ChrisG I can use the url to show Image in browser and get that URL in console.log but when I am storing the URL in userProfile key for localStorage and then using console.log to show the key in URL, then I am getting the Message "undefined"

Comment: @AbhishekMehandiratta I can use the same URL in my website for showing the profile picture, but can't store it in localStorage

Comment: Is `url` a string? When you inspect your local storage in the browser's dev tools, can you see the URL? How are you trying to read back the value? We need more information.

Comment: From what I can tell, the URL was not obtained correctly. Just not enough information to help you out.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes it is a string, I can read see it in the console.log in Dev Tools